# googlebot crawls PLP pages and SERVER is down due to hugh CPU load

Tags: magento2, seo

We are seeing very HIGH cpu load on our magento2.2.3 cloud and the site is getting down. This happens when googlebot crawls the category pages. LHN is there. Also we have infinite Ajax scroll feature implemented.

Comment: did you enable elasticsearch?

Comment: Hi Yes, 

We have elasticsearch , LHN, ajax scroll modules installed there. All modues are from Amasty